# What is it called when an object member returns the object, enabling you to string method calls?

Tags: design-patterns

Perhaps I'm just not using the right Google-age. But I am trying to remember what the term is for when you return the object from one of it members to enable you to do something similar:

```
class obj {
    obj function method()
    {
        return this
    }
}

obj->method()->method()->method()->method()
```

I used to know this but it has totally escaped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method chaining <sup>[1](http://martinfowler.com/dslwip/MethodChaining.html)</sup><sup>,</sup> <sup>[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Fluent Interface was the term I was after. Method chaining was the key to finding it in search though.